# How to bind a new rowAdd even to an ObservableCollection item

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid` binding to an `ObservableCollection`, the user can add/ remove row. In the first column, when the user double click on the cell a new window should appear but it doesn't happen until he leave the cell then re-enter it.
After debugging, I found the problem that `DataGridTextColumn` didn't get initialized until the second double click. 
What is my wrong with my binding?

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CellDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="TeachersDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TeacherInfoList, IsAsync=True}"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="18" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" Background="#FFEEECEC">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="الرقم" Binding="{Binding Path=Num, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="لقب الموظف و إسمه" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="مهنته" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="المؤسسة أو مكان العمل" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=SchoolName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="الولاية" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Province, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="طبيعة التفتيش" Binding="{Binding Path=Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

C#:

```
private void CellDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = null;
    TextBox textBox = null;

    cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell == null)
    //if (cell == null || (cell.Column.DisplayIndex == 0 || cell.Column.DisplayIndex == 5))
        {
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("cell66");
    DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(cell);
    int rowIndex = row.GetIndex();
    //MessageBox.Show(rowIndex.ToString());
    textBox = cell.Content as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("textBox");
    try
    {
        TeachersListWindow TeachersListW = new TeachersListWindow(this, rowIndex);
        TeachersListW.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition here.
Since the DataGrid is not readonly, when you double click a cell, it change its DataTemplate from Display template into Edit template.

In Display DataTemplate of DataGridTextColumn there is only TextBlock element.

In Edit DataTemplate of DataGridTextColumn there is the TextBox element.

You will have trouble catching the TextBox element like that.

Better option is to have doubleclick event handler on the row, and use it's DataContext to extract the data you want.